# How to access log file with tensorboard on anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorboard

I've made a NN model with Keras in a Ananconda enviroment (i'm using Jupiter).
I would want to access the log file that I'm writing with tensorboard, and I would like to see the accuracy and the loss function graphs.

However, when I try to access to the log file from the terminal this error occurs: AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.util' has no attribute 'PersistentOpEvaluator'

Anyone can help me to write these graphs and to see them opening tensorboard?

This is my code:

```
    hidden_size = 256

    sl_model = keras.models.Sequential()
    [...]
    sl_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(max_length, activation='softmax')) 
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    sl_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])

    batch_size = 128
    epochs = 3

    # Let's print a summary of the model
    sl_model.summary()

    #I'd like to access to this file
    cbk = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard("logging/keras_model")

    print("\nStarting training...")
    sl_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
      shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_dev, y_dev), callbacks=[cbk])
```

How can I fix this? thank you!

Comment: what tensorflow version do you use? You can access tensorboard from jupyter in tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: I'm using version 1.12

Comment: Are you using stand alone `keras` or `tf.keras`?

Comment: I'm using tensorflow.keras as keras

Comment: Do you have multiple anaconda environments? Or maybe you have pip tensorflow installation as well?

Comment: I have only one anaconda environment. Yes, I have installed pip tensorflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191563/discussion-between-vlad-and-pierfrancesco).

Answer (score 0):

You must delete `tensorboard` directory in site-packages then `pip install tensorboard --upgrade` supposing your `tensorflow` version is up-to-date.

Comment: It has been required me to use the tensorflow version 1.12... so I can not upgrade it

Comment: Did you try upgrading only tensorboard ?